# HSQL - Adding a new column in the query based on an IF condition

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I need to generate a column, where in each row it checks if the `Bestand` is less than, equal or greater than `Minbestand`. If so the new column called `Bestandsbewertung` needs to give out `Mangel`, `Mindestbestand` or `Überfluß` respectively.

```
SELECT IF(Bestand < Minbestand, 'Mangel', IF(Bestand = MinBestand, 'Mindestbestand', 'Überstand')) AS Bestandsbewertung, Teile.*
FROM Teile
```

I tried this code but HSQL says it doesn't know `IF`.

[This is what the Table looks like if it helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6ODV.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems HSQL doesn't accept `IF`. After some trial and error I came to this solution to the problem.

```
SELECT Teile.*,
       CASE Bestand WHEN < MinBestand THEN 'Mangel'
                    WHEN = MinBestand THEN 'Mindestbestand'
                    WHEN > MinBestand THEN 'Überfluß' END AS Bestandsbewertung
FROM Teile
```

It seems to work without any issues.

Comment: Can also write it as `CASE Bestand WHEN < MinBestand THEN 'Mangel' WHEN  = MinBestand THEN 'Mindestbestand' WHEN > MinBestand THEN 'Überfluß' END `